# Symfony 1.4 - Updating an action variable from component

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I've got a scenario where I need to manipulate a variable on my action controller from within the component.

Basically, I have a component where I'm executing some Doctrine Queries and then outputting them in a component file. In my action method I call this component to send it back to the browser (the request is made via AJAX)

`$content = $this->getComponent('documents', 'list');`

What I want to do is access the row count of the queries executed in the component method, but from within the action method. I have tried defining my variable in the action:

`$this->rowCount = 0;`

and then updating it in the component:

`$this->rowCount = 10;`

but when I `var_dump` the rowCount in the action after retrieving the component content, it's still 0.

Has anyone ever done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the value in the `parameterHodler` will do the job

See : http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/02-Exploring-Symfony-s-Code#chapter_02_sub_parameter_holders